# non-blocking(event driven I/O) vs. blocking I/O

Tags: events, node.js, io, blocking, nonblocking

Recently I stumbled across this pretty slick JS library called nodeJS that acts like a server side JS.

The main feature of the language being Evented I/O which gives the inherent capacity of I/O being completely non-blocking using callbacks!!!

My question is, if this kind of completely non-blocking I/O mechanism existed in the past (given event driven I/O has been around for a long time), why aren't they more popular in high level languages like C# and Java (although Java has NIO implementation that supports non-blocking I/O)?

Currently, a simple file read/write operation results in complete I/O blocking which is not the case with event driven I/O.

I'd like to gain a better understanding of event driven I/O and how it is different from what we have in Java.

Comment: I am curious why you think Java/C# does not have async IO?

Comment: You mean using Java NIO package??. I've never used it but I know it's very capable. I will change the question to address this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O

> A multiplexed, non-blocking I/O facility for writing scalable servers

.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx

```
public IAsyncResult BeginReceive(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int size,
    SocketFlags socketFlags,
    AsyncCallback callback,
    Object state
)
```

Comment: Kirk excellent!!. But can you explain more about New I/O. Is it event driven??. I am trying to compare it with nodeJS. The reason why nodeJS is so popular is because of it's event driven I/O.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's "event" driven in the sense you mean, but this is an excellent tutorial: http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/

Comment: @A_Var: An event-driven engine is actually just an abstraction of state machines. In languages where there is no built-in event-driven engine most developers simply write their own state machine using a while loop and switch statements (or a dispatch table). Sometimes developers can be bothered enough to generalize their state machine implementation to make an API out of it resulting in an event-driven library for the language. An example of this is Python's Twisted framework.

Answer (score 3):

Tcl had event driven I/O from the 1990's (if I'm not mistaken). Certainly before 2000 because it was when tclhttpd beat Apache in benchmark tests sometime in 2000 that people really started paying attention to non-blocking I/O. When people saw that, they started re-writing web servers. One of the early result of that was Lighttpd: one of the first non-blocking web servers written in C. At that time, using event-driven I/O in tcl via the [fileevent](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/fileevent.htm) command was already considered standard practice in the tcl world.

AOLserver had (and still does) have a tcl core and it's hosting one of the busiest sites on the web (at least in the early days): http://www.aol.com/. Though the server itself is written in C, it uses tcl's C API to implement event handling and I/O. The reason AOLserver used tcl's I/O subsystem is because it uses tcl as a scripting language and the developers thought that since someone else have written it then might as well use it.

I believe AOLserver was first released in 1995. That should confirm that event-driven I/O was already available in tcl back in the mid 1990s.

Tcl is one of the earliest, if not **the** earliest language to have an event-driven engine built it. The event subsystem was originally implemented for the Tk library and was later merged into tcl itself.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there's a widespread *perception* that multithreading is easier than event-driven, since in multithreaded programming every thread has a simple sequential flow of execution, while event-driven consists of lots of small fragments of code.

Of course, this is better stated elsewhere, see for example Q.2 of [state-threads FAQ](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net/docs/faq.html).

Answer (score -4):

Java has bad support even for basic file I/O. These languages are created for fast creation of portable GUI applications, and not for optimized and OS dependent low level I/O operations.

Comment: I can't tell, was this answer a joke?

Comment: This doesn't compare with evented I/O and criticising Java I/O. Yes Java non blocking I/O via multi-threading (not pure non-blocking I/O though) is different from event driven I/O(which is pure non-blocking I/O) but each has it's own pro's and con's. Please support your statement with examples.